# Can someone explain the math behind this basic probability problem

Tags: probability

> The integers 0 through 9 are written on ten pieces of paper and put in
>    a bag. A piece of paper is chosen at random from the bag, the number
>    is recorded, then replaced, and a second piece of paper is chosen and
>    that number is also recorded. The two recorded numbers are written
>    next to each other to make a two digit integer. The numbers 00,
>    01,...,09 are not counted as two-digit integers. For example, if 3 and
>    5 are chosen, then the number could be 35 or 53. If 0 and 6 are
>    chosen, then there is only one possibility, which is 60. If 9 and 9
>    are chosen, then there is only one possibility, which is 99. What is
>    the probability of making 47?

The hint it gives is the following:

> What are the smallest and largest numbers that could be made? And, to calculate the probabilities, in each case list the numbers that are possible. The smallest number that could be made is 10 and the largest number is 99, so there are 99 - 9 = 90 different possible two digit numbers.

So the answer is $\frac1{90}$ but I'm not sure I understand why. I'll lay out my logic and then hopefully someone can correct me where I go wrong.

So you can make $47$ two ways, you can draw a $4$ then a $7$, or a $7$ then a $4$. So an equation would look like:

$P(4)P(7) + P(7)P(4) = 2P(4)P(7) = 2\left(\frac1{10} * \frac1{10}\right) = \frac1{50}$

The help guide after answering the question only says this:

> There is only one way to make 47, so the probability of making 47 is
>    1/90

Which isn't very helpful

Comment: Simply put: You cannot understand their solution because they are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly calculated the chance that getting one four and one seven is $1/50$.  Assuming you then randomly pick between the two possible numbers, the chance you get $47$ is then $1/100$.  The problem does not specify what happens if you draw $00$.  The chance for getting any multiple of $10$ would be $1/50$ as you have $1/50$ chance to get the right digits but only have one number to choose from.  There are $72$ two digit numbers with different nonzero digits, each with probability $1/100, 9$ two digit numbers with the same nonzero digits, also with probability $1/100, 9$ multiples of $10$ with probability $1/50$  We have accounted for a total of $99/100$ and don't know what to do with the $1/100$ chance we draw $00$, so the sum is $1$ as expected.  I don't know where they get $1/90$

Comment: updated my post, with the hint it gives in case that helps. It's a GRE problem, but it made me second guess my ability to do basic probability math

Comment: The hint is badly wrong and my answer shows why.  The hint assumes that all the numbers you can form are equally probable, which is not true.  Numbers like $10, 20, \ldots$ are twice as likely as the others.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of picking `4` and `7` is $2/100$ as you stated, the probability of making `47` instead of `74` out of those picks is $1/2$, so the probability of drawing numbers *and* making `47` with them is $1/100$.

What they appear to have done is decide that there are $9$ ways to pick a non-zero digit for the tens and $10$ ways to pick another digit for the units, so there are $90$ valid picks.   This is *bad* reasoning as it does not model how the selection process was posed.

The reason you cannot understand their solution is because they are *wrong*; since the selection from the $91$ possible results (two digit numbers *and* `00`) is *biased*; they are not equally probable.

Comment: Why is $00$ valid?

Comment: @BrianTung It is a possible result. The problem just did not specify how it should be handled.

Comment: Hmm.  It seemed as excluded as $01$ through $09$.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you call 00-09 "invalid" doesn't magically shrink the sample size to 90. The sample size is 100. And the probability that you can form 47 from 2 random picks is (2/10)*(1/10) = 2/100 = 1/50

If half the time we end up with 74 instead then the probability we arrive at 47 is (1/2)*(1/50) = 1/100